# Flutter : When I rotate a horizontal ListView by Transform.rotate, the left and right edges are cut off

Tags: flutter

When I use Transform.rotate to make a horizontal ListView diagonal as shown below, it becomes diagonal, but the left and right edges are cut off.

Is there a way to display without clipping the left and right edges, or is there a widget that can be used for that?

I came up with a way to use the Stack widget to overlay the left and right edges with strips of gradation and make them invisible.
I've actually tried it and it's fine, but I thought I'd ask if there is another way.

I think this is happening because the screen width is passed from the parent as a constraint, but is there any way to disable the constraint?
Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Animated Icons',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: -math.pi / 20,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 6,
                      itemBuilder: (context, innerIndex) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: 200.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            color:
                                Colors.red.withOpacity(1.0 - 0.1 * innerIndex),
                          ),
                          child:Center(child:Text(innerIndex.toString()),),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            height:100.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child:Center(
              child:Text('title'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding radius to the Container above ListView.builder,

`decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
  ),`

Comment: you would need `OverflowBox` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code using OverflowBox, the left and right corners are no longer cut off.

```
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: OverflowBox(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*1.2,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: -math.pi / 20,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 6,
                      itemBuilder: (context, innerIndex) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: 200.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            color:
                                Colors.red.withOpacity(1.0 - 0.1 * innerIndex),
                          ),
                          child:Center(child:Text(innerIndex.toString()),),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```